# What is the code in Envelope?

Tags: plot-explanation, envelope

I recently watched *[Envelope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUgh3EfjDq8&oref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DxUgh3EfjDq8&has_verified=1)* which is about a guy in Russia who writes fake letters to fake people all around the world so he can collect the return stamps/postmarks. He sends his last envelope to New Zealand and mysteriously gets a reply from someone who apparently knows him. This response prompts the KGB to arrest the protagonist and bring him back to Moscow because they think he has been sending coded messages. Once the protagonist boards the plane he admits that the letters were a code, but you would have to look at his whole life to understand the code. This brings me to my question. Is there really a code, and if so what is it?

At the end of the film there is a dedication to [Yevgeny Petrov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(film)). This is a real person who was a Russian writer between the 1920's and 1940's who did [travel around the world](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Interestingly there appears to be what reads like an urban myth [with a similar](http://survinat.com/2013/03/mystery-of-life-and-death-yevgeny-petrov/) [plot line](http://www.nztramping.com/experiences/a-mysterious-story-of-evgeny-petrov-and-new-zealand/) to the movie involving Yevgeny Petrov. This explains the dedication but not the "code" mentioned in the movie. Maybe someone with more familiarity with Russian culture might be able to shed some light on this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

> Once the protagonist boards the plane he admits that the letters were a code, but you would have to look at his whole life to understand the code.

I understood differently. Here're the actual lines spoken in the movie:

> *Yevgeny Petrov (YP):* You know, you were right, there is a code.
>   *KGB General (KG):* I knew this. What is it?
>   *YP:* You just have to step back far enough, and you will see it.
>   *KG:* See what?
>   *YP:* My life.

So, yes, there was a greater meaning behind the envelopes, and it was Yevgeny's own life. This line alludes to his lifelong hobby, to his supernatural experience, and to a premonition of his own death.